# Java pattern to access attributes from many classes/threads

Tags: java, multithreading, pojo

I intend to parse a config file. This will happen once at the startup of my application. 
During it's execution the application has several threads. Each thread needs some of the parsed config parameters (but doesn't need to change them).

how can I do this with plain Java - economical of resources? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the class that parses the config file as a singleton.

Parse the config before you start the other threads

Get the code in the threads to refer to the singleton object containing the parsed config.

Comment: Nice! For the sake of thread safety it's recommended to instantiate the Sigleton object by the JVM on it's first access. public class Singleton { private static Singleton instance = new Singleton(); .... } Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class which will be the holder for configuration, parse it at static initializer (guaranteed to be thread safe and happen only once during class loading unless you will programatically load it via ClassLoader) and hold a static (and final needed) reference to the parsed config object representation. It seems to be quite economical.

Or you can just implement the classic singleton pattern for loader/holder class.